# MySQL add new column on specific position

Tags: mysql, alter-table

If i would like to add new column Remarks as first column, i will employ following code

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD Remarks VARCHAR(100) NULL FIRST
```

What if i wanna add before the column which name ColumnX in MySQL?

Comment: You can add it _after_ a specific column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only positioning options when adding a new column are `FIRST` and `AFTER col_name`. So to put the column before `ColumnX`, you have to find out what column is currently before it, e.g. `ColumnY`, and then use:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD Remarks VARCHAR(100) NULL AFTER ColumnY
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only add a column alter a specific column:

Form [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

> To add a column at a specific position within a table row, use FIRST
>   or AFTERcol_name. The default is to add the column last. You can also
>   use FIRST and AFTER in CHANGE or MODIFY operations to reorder columns
>   within a table

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD Remarks VARCHAR(100) AFTER ColumnX
```